# Can I open the webview widget with an implicit intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

I know I can open up a webview widget using an explicit intent, but is there a way that I can open up a webview widget using implicit intent?

It seems that I cannot use:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent web_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(web_intent);
```

How can I achieve opening the website on my webview widget?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve opening the website on my webview widget?

Call `loadUrl()` on that `WebView`, passing in your URL.

Comment: Thanks. Also have a follow up question, which is if I want to make the tab with the webview widget visible when I click on the link, should I use:  "webView.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE); "? I tried it before, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: @smart_cookie: That depends entirely on what you are using for tabs. If they are based on a `ViewPager`, call `setCurrentItem()` on the `ViewPager` to switch pages.